# Code in IndexController::indexAction executes before each request

Tags: session, routes, phalcon

Is it a bug or a feature?

I have two controllers IndexController and TestController.

The first one looks like this:

```
class IndexController extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $products = $this->basket->get('products', []);
        $products[] = uniqid('index.index');
        $this->basket->set('products', $products);
    }

    public function testAction()
    {
        var_dump($this->basket->products);
    }
}
```

I just save an array in a session with indexAction and show that data in testAction.

For the first request output for index/test is an empty array. But the second and all following requests add one new element. If I comment line `$this->basket->set('products', $products);` then the next request to index/test will add another value to array but after that extra pushing to array does not happen.

Then I add

```
class TestController extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $products = $this->basket->get('products', []);
        $products[] = uniqid('test.index');
        $this->basket->set('products', $products);
        die();
    }

    public function testAction()
    {
        var_dump($this->basket->products);
        die();
    }
}
```

But for request test/test I again get changing in session variable.

Looks like that route index/index always executes before any other routes. Is it a feature, bug or some sort of misconfiguration? I use standard configuration for multimodule application from official documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is more than likely because your browser is hitting /favicon.ico in the background. I've been stung by this a number of times across different frameworks.

Try putting a favicon.ico file (or a rule to block that path) and see if the problem persists.